# Mocking function on default export of hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook APIGateway calling another custom hook http. I'd like to mock the promise function sendHttpRequest to test sendAPIRequest. With this code, I am getting "Rejected to value: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]"
I am trying to avoid any __mock__ files. If I mock axios, apiGateway.test passes.
How can I mock a function sendHttpRequest on the default export of useHttp?

http.js

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useHttp = () => {
    const sendRequest = useCallback((url, method, body) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios({ method: method, url: url, data: body, config: { crossDomain: true } })
                .then((response) => {
                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }, []);

    return {
        sendHttpRequest: sendRequest,
    };
};

export default useHttp;
```

apiGateway.js

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import useHttp from '../abstract/http';
import configuration from '../../endpoints';

const useApiGateway = () => {
    const { sendHttpRequest } = useHttp();
    const apiGatewayBaseUrl = configuration.API_GATEWAY_BASE_URL;
    const apiGatewayPath = configuration.LAMBDA_USER_ENDPOINT;

    const sendRequest = useCallback((body) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            sendHttpRequest(apiGatewayBaseUrl + apiGatewayPath, 'get', body)
                .then((response) => {
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }, []);

    return {
        sendApiRequest: sendRequest,
    };
};

export default useApiGateway;
```

apiGateway.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

import useApiGateway from './apiGateway';
import useHttp from '../abstract/http';
jest.mock('../abstract/http', () => jest.fn());
describe('hook/aws/apiGateway', () => {
    let result;
    beforeEach(() => {});

    it('should send GET request with no error', () => {
        //TODO mock http instead of axios
        let response = { data: '<html>Hello</html>' };
        useHttp.mockImplementation(() => ({
            sendHttpRequest: jest.fn(() => {}),
        }));
        let { sendHttpRequest } = useHttp();
        sendHttpRequest.mockResolvedValue(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(response);
            })
        );
        result = renderHook(() => useApiGateway()).result;
        console.log(useHttp());
        act(() => {
            return expect(result.current.sendApiRequest({})).resolves.toEqual(response.data);
        });
    });

});
```

full error

```
Error: expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

Received promise rejected instead of resolved
Rejected to value: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]

    at expect (.../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:138:15)
    at .../apiGateway.test.js:29:11
```

Answer (score 0):

your mock should return a promise (rather than attempting to mock out the promise lib)

example:

```
function myMockRequest() {
    return Promise.resolve({ mockResponse });
}
```